# Method inheritance issue

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods

When I attempt to create a 'BJ_player' object:

```
player = BJ_player(name, number_chips)
```

I receive:

> TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (3 given).

I've used the same methodology to inherit from 'BJ_Hand' as I did to inherit from 'Hand'.

Could someone please explain?

This first class is located in 'cardsmodule':

```
class Hand(object):
    """A hand of playing cards"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def __str__(self):
        if self.cards:
            rep = ""
            for card in self.cards:
                rep += str(card) + "\t"
        else:
            rep = "<empty>"
        return rep
```

```
class BJ_hand(cardsmodule.Hand):
    """A BlackJack hand"""

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(BJ_hand, self).__init__()
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.name + "\t" + super(BJ_hand,self).__str__()
        if self.total:
            rep += "(" + str(self.total) + ")"
        return rep

class BJ_player(BJ_hand):
    """A BlackJack player"""
    def __init__(self, number_chips):
        super(BJ_player, self).__init__()
        #self.name = name
        self.number_chips = number_chips

    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.name + " has " + str(self.number_chips) + " chips.\n"
        rep += super(BJ_player, self).__init__()
```

Comment: Your `BJ_player` class constructor doesn't expect a `name` parameter. You need to add a `name` parameter and pass it on to `super(BJ_player, self).__init__(name)`.

Comment: This isn't really a multiple-inheritance issue, despite the title and tag. Multiple inheritance is when a child class has more than one direct parent classes (e.g. a mother and a father), not when you inherit from a class that itself inherits from another class (e.g. a father and a grandfather).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined an `__init__` method that only takes *one* argument (plus `self`):

```
class BJ_player(BJ_hand):
    """A BlackJack player"""
    def __init__(self, number_chips):
        #              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There is no parameter for `name`, but you are trying to pass that in:

```
player = BJ_player(name, number_chips)
#                  ^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Python doesn't look to all base `__init__` methods for you; it'll only 'see' `BJ_player`. If you wanted to pass in a `name` value for `BJ_hand.__init__`, then `BJ_player.__init__()` *must* accept that as an argument. You can then pass it on via the `super().__init__()` call:

```
class BJ_player(BJ_hand):
    """A BlackJack player"""
    def __init__(self, name, number_chips):
        super(BJ_player, self).__init__(name)
```

Note how the `name` parameter from the method is now passed on in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

This gives no errors on py2.7 and py3.5:

```
class Hand(object):
    """A hand of playing cards"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def __str__(self):
        if self.cards:
            rep = ""
            for card in self.cards:
                rep += str(card) + "\t"
        else:
            rep = "<empty>"
        return rep

class BJ_hand(Hand):
    """A BlackJack hand"""

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(BJ_hand, self).__init__()
        self.name = name


    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.name + "\t" + super(BJ_hand,self).__str__()
        if self.total:
            rep += "(" + str(self.total) + ")"
        return rep

class BJ_player(BJ_hand):
    """A BlackJack player"""
    def __init__(self, number_chips):
        super(BJ_player, self).__init__('aName')
        self.number_chips = number_chips

    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.name + " has " + str(self.number_chips) + " chips.\n"
        rep += super(BJ_player, self).__init__()

b = BJ_player (3)
```

Comment: That code works. But when I start my game of BlackJack I need to pass BJ_player a name and number of chips, ie player =  BJ_player(name, number_chips). That throws the same error. There's something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

The `BJ_player` class has a problem. Modified the class to this:

```
class BJ_player(BJ_hand):
    """A BlackJack player"""
    def __init__(self, name, number_chips):
        super(BJ_player, self).__init__(name)
        self.name = name
        self.number_chips = number_chips

    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.name + " has " + str(self.number_chips) + " chips.\n"
        rep += super(BJ_player, self).__init__(self.name)
```

Tried this and it works

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers have (mostly) correctly diagnosed the specific issue you were describing (not accepting `name` in `BJ_player.__init__` and passing it on in the `super` call), I think there's a larger design issue that may cause you other problems while working with your classes.

Specifically, the relationship between a player and the cards in their hand is not well represented by inheritance. Inheritance is often described as an "IS-A" relationship. For example, it would make sense to define a `Dog` class that inherits from an `Animal` parent class, since every Dog *is* an Animal.

This isn't the case with players and hands. A blackjack player *is not* a certain kind of hand of cards. Each player *has a* hand of cards. A "HAS-A" relationship between objects is best implemented with composition. That is, a `BJ_player` instance should have a `Hand` instance as an instance variable. This might free up your design in other ways. For instance, when it's not busy in a casino, one player can play several hands at once at the same table. That would be impossible to represent with inheritance, but it would be fairly easy to change the single `Hand` instance being saved in an instance variable on the `Player` instance to a list of one-or-more `Hand` instances.

I'd also suggest that the `name` attribute you're storing on `BJ_hand` is really more appropriate as an attribute on the player. It might still make sense to have a `BJ_hand` class, which could deal with things like counting the value of the cards dealt (and if you've busted yet or not), but you may need to think a bit on which attributes make sense to store on the hand and which are more appropriate elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks very much. That design is straight from my beginner's book. However I see exactly what you mean now you have reminded me of the 'has-a, is-a' relationship. I will make a version as you've described.